# Why No Chain Rule With Derivative of Inverse Functions

Tags: calculus

When using the formula to find the derivative of inverse functions [if g(x)=f^-1(x), then f'(x)=1/g'(f(x))], why is it that when using the formula to solve equations, for the bottom part of the equation, g'(f(x)), we only take the derivative of 'g(x)' and just input 'f(x)' for (x), without applying the chain rule (i.e. then multiplying it by f'(x)), esp. since in this formula we're deriving g'(f(x)) with respect to 'x', not 'f(x)'? Thanks.

Comment: Please use MathJax to improve the readability of this. It's impossible to decipher otherwise.

Comment: Can you give an example of when you used the formula in this way to solve an equation? I think it would make it clearer what you're misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We *do* use the Chain Rule.

You start with $g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$. Assuming that $f’(x)\neq 0$ (at the point in question) to ensure the differentiability of $g$, we can then proceed. We have:
$$g(f(x)) = x.$$
Taking derivatives with respect to $x$ on both sides **and using the Chain Rule**, we get
$$g’(f(x))f’(x) = 1.$$
Since $f’(x)\neq 0$, then solving for $g’(f(x))$, we get
$$g’(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f’(x)}.$$
Now: set $y=f(x)$. Then $x = g(y)$. Plugging $y$ for $f(x)$ on the left, and $g(y)$ for $x$ on the right, we get
$$g’(y) = \frac{1}{f’(g(y))},\qquad \text{where }f(x)=y.$$

Comment: just a small remark: there is infact no need to assume $f'(x) \neq 0$, because the product being equal to 1 already implies both factors are non zero

Comment: @peek-a-boo: It’s badly located, but the assumption is necessary; it is implicit in the assumption that $g=f^{-1}$ is differentiable.